Issue with `handleOrientationChange`. Image do not switching
I am trying to switch site logo on device orientation change. But it's do not handle orientation changes and require update.
// tracking in realtime
function handleOrientationChange() {
    const logoImage = document.getElementById('logo');   

    if(window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
        isPortrait = true;
    } else {
        isPortrait = false;
    }
    
    if (isMobile) {   
        if(isPortrait) {
            logoImage.src = '/images/logo_small.svg';
        } else { // return back to original
            logoImage.src = '/images/logo.svg'; 
        }
    }

}

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", handleOrientationChange);

// Called when the orientation is changed
screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", handleOrientationChange);

// Called as soon as the page loads
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    handleOrientationChange();
});

<nav>
    <a href="/">
        <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="/images/logo.svg">
    </a>
        <ul class="nav-menu" >
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>    
</nav>

Video https://youtube.com/shorts/ZbiEu9PywEw?feature=share

WHat version of IOS are you using?

Latest version, 17.5.1

Hope it helps
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
const logoImage = document.getElementById('logo');

    function handleOrientationChange() {
        if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
            logoImage.src = './images/logo_small.svg';
        } else {
            logoImage.src = './images/logo.svg';
        }
    }
    handleOrientationChange();

    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", handleOrientationChange);
});


it do not switch to logo_small on portrait mode on phone
